# Apostrophe site giving CKEditor "editor-plugin-required" error

Tags: ckeditor, apostrophe-cms

My apostrophe-rich-text widgets give me a `editor-plugin-required. {plugin: "toolbar", requiredBy: "clipboard"}` error in the console. I'm trying to add 'Bold' to the toolbar and it shows up, but when I click it nothing happens.

Additionally, the node_modules folder is gone from my local application and github repo. I'm fairly new to node, so I'm not sure if that's normal, but I'm pretty sure it was there during production. I don't have any modules that extend the apostrophe-areas module, so I'm not sure where the error is coming from.

How can I get the error to go away and the toolbar to actually make changes?

Comment: We have never seen this behavior with Apostrophe. Re: node_modules, it must exist or apostrophe cannot start up at all, so it is probably actually there when you run your app. It is not in github because it does not make sense to commit it - instead "npm install" is part of the process of checking out and getting started in dev, or of deployment in production.

Comment: Can you reproduce this problem in our boilerplate project? Or in another project that can be shared on github and does not have a great deal of unrelated code?

Comment: I downloaded the apostrophe-open-museum code and it does not show me a node_modules folder but runs fine. Do you know how I can get it show the folder? I've done npm install, but still no folder.

As far as replicating it, I downloaded the boilerplate and simply added a default and a home page and it's giving me the same error as my full project. It's located here:
https://github.com/davidagud/apostrophe-boilerplate-david.

Comment: The folder is definitely there, it cannot run without it, apostrophe is in that folder. How are you viewing the folders exactly?

Comment: The folder is not *committed to git* but it exists *on your hard drive* after you type npm install. (Do not commit it to git.)

Comment: Gotcha.

I was able to replicate the `editor-plugin-required. {plugin: "toolbar", requiredBy: "clipboard"}` error in a fairly bare code in https://github.com/davidagud/apostrophe-boilerplate-david. Do you have any ideas what's causing it/how I can fix it? Thanks

Comment: I can reproduce this error but only if the toolbar option is missing or empty.

https://github.com/apostrophecms/apostrophe/issues/1875

Comment: If I put toolbar: [ 'Bold' ] it works fine in my tests. Can you update the repo to show the problem when the toolbar is not empty?

I agree that it should work when the toolbar is empty. If toolbar is not specified at all it should probably print a warning because the developer probably just forgot, but it shouldn't print an error, and if toolbar is an empty array it should let you just edit plain text on the page I suppose.